# Keyboard does not get hide in flutter version 3.10.4

Tags: flutter, keyboard, flutter-bloc

I have a stateless class with a pageview in it. And I put 3 widgets in pageview. On the first page I have a textfield and when input is done I want to hide keyboard.

It was working on flutter_bloc older version, after i update flutter bloc to 3.10.4 it does not work.

I am using a Gesture Detector for pageview also other parent child or even widget itself it is not working.